# how to install npm if couldn't resolve npmjs.org

Tags: curl, node.js

when m doing curl it says could not resolve host what can i do ?

```
curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh

curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'npmjs.org'
```

http://npmjs.org/

/etc/resolv.conf

```
search x1
nameserver x2
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

nslookup result

```
 nslookup google.com
Server:         x1
Address:        x1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find google.com: No answer
```

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find google.com: No answer

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your DNS is working fine:

```
$ nslookup google.com
```

If not, change to Google's DNS and try again:

```
# echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf
# echo "nameserver 8.8.4.4" >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

---

> i can access internet by proxy

You can make `curl` use HTTP proxy with:

```
$ curl -x proxyhost:port http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh
```

Comment: pls check question with your answer result .

Comment: Delete two first lines in `/etc/resolv.conf` and try again.

Comment: after deleteing when m doing `nslookup google.com` it gives  ;; `connection timed out; no servers could be reached`

Comment: Do you have Internet connection? `ping 8.8.8.8`?

Comment: i can  access internet by proxy , and ping result is `PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.`

Comment: Try to set proxy for `curl`.